# Как пропатчить программу если в исходной строке меньше символов чем в пропатченой?

Tags: hex, reverse-engineering

Представим, что я с помощью IDA пытаюсь заменить строку "Hello" на "Testt". В таком случае можно спокойно заменить `48 65 6c 6c 6f (Hello)` на `54 65 73 74 74 (Testt)`, например.

Вместо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поставить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таком случае всё работает корректно. В случае, если мне нужно заменить "Hello" на "Test", можно просто добавить в конце `00`, чтобы "обрезать" ненужные символы.

Однако, что если я хочу заменить "Hello" на "Testttt"? Добавить ещё байтов, как я понимаю, нельзя. Оно перезаписывает следующие байты и меняет следующую строку, и я так и не понял как можно дописать что то в строку.

Comment: В общем случае никак.

Comment: Что значит "в общем случае"?

Comment: Предположу, что: 1. Найти свободное место в сегменте нужного типа (вероятно, у него имеется неиспользуемый хвост, но я боюсь, что тогда вся адресация в файле поедет, так что с учётом плоской адресации в windows, можно попробовать добавить в конец новый сегмент и поместить в него). 2. Записать туда строку. 3. Найти все ссылки на исходную строку и заменить их новыми.

Comment: Кстати, с уменьшением длины ещё могло понадобиться где-то менять число с длиной.

Comment: @Akina, а есть причины, почему описанное мной в каких-то случаях может не работать? Или просто очень сложно реализовать?

Comment: @Qwertiy не понимаю о чем вы, простое затирание конца нулями вроде как работает, нигде число с длиной не менял

Comment: @user580397, если что-то не понадобилось, это не означает, что оно не понадобится никогда. Во многих языках строки хранятся с длиной перед строкой - подозреваю, что в бинарнике она тоже порписана.

Comment: Это Download Master - он написан на делфи. И вот: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRjMS.png. Хотя, может это секция ресурсов и там в принципе так положено, а делфи не при чём. Но такое точно может встречаться.